# Convert text string to hexadecimal using flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, hex, flex4

I want to convert MAC Address into hexadecimal string using flash builder..
I used this code

```
var networkInterface : Object =  NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
var networkInfo  : Object = networkInterface[0];
var physicalAddress : String = networkInfo.hardwareAddress.toString();

txtreq.text = physicalAddress + "-" + txtserial.text

var reqcode:uint = uint(txtreq.text);

var reqcode1:String = reqcode.toString(16);

txtact.text = reqcode1;
```

When I run the application,

**txtserial.text = 123** and **physicalAddress = C6-17-31-A9-EF-FF**...

but **txtact.text** got **0**.

Then how I fix the problem and In flex Builder how I convert **FF-FF-FF-FF-FF** like text into hexadecimal code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use parseInt(reqcode,16) instead of reqcode.toString(16);